# Oracle maintaining a column based on the values of other columns in the same table

Tags: sql, oracle

In student table what is the query to create a default constraint on the column address as the value should get updated automatically based on the data of City+''+street+''+HouseNo.

Comment: Which RDBMS is it, Oracle or MySQL?

Comment: I think you might be looking at a `TRIGGER`.  At least in MySQL, there's no dynamic processing associated with a column's default value.

Comment: Creating a constraint is a DML statement, not an SQL query.

Comment: Can anyone tell me query in oracle for this?

Comment: actually 'address','city','street' and 'HouseNo' are four columns in the table student.When I insert the values such as address,city and HouseNo then the address column should automatically get the value address+City+Street.

Comment: I think you want a view, using this table as a base table.

Answer (score 2):

Well if the column is based on the values in other columns then I would not create that new column at all as it would be redundant. Construct the value when you query the table.

You could look into virtual columns as a means for ensuring that the definition of the constructed value is consistent and that it could be indexed, however. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28279/chapter1.htm#FEATURENO07254

Comment: actually 'address','city','street' and 'HouseNo' are columns in the table student.When I insert the values such as address,city and HouseNo then the address column should automatically get the value address+City+Street. I want the query.

Comment: So you have four columns in the table: address, city, street, and houseno. When the last three are populated you want address to be changed to equal those three concatanated together, separated by a space?

Comment: Yes right there are four columns and I want to concatenate the value from other three columns automatically using default constraint

Comment: So what I am saying is that you address column should either be dropped completely and the required value be selected from the table (as you are violating one of the normal forms), or you should redefine address as a virtual column. The way that you'd have to keep address updated automatically would be through a trigger, not a default value or a constraint, and using triggers in that way obscures the workings of your system and makes the code more complex. A virtual column would be a lot more efficient and supportable.